# Move only some fields of document of a database to other

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

Suppose I have 2 collections A and B as defined
A -->

```
{ "firstname":"sonu", "lastname":"monu" ,"email":"abc@xyz.com", "password":"##", "verified":"false"}
```

and collection B also has a Schema defined as -->

```
{ firstname: String , lastname: String , email: String , password: String }
```

Now I need to move document of A to B if  `'verified':'true'`and set my B with values of A

Comment: At the time of setting "verified": true (creating/updating) of document of A, create a document of B with your required fields.